# Foreach repeating code

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I have this arrays:

```
array(2117) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(21) "AAAAAAA"
    ["format"]=>
    string(7) "160x600"
    ["count"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(21) "AAAAAAA"
    ["format"]=>
    string(7) "300x250"
    ["count"]=>
    int(135)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(22) "BBBBB"
    ["format"]=>
    string(7) "300x250"
    ["count"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(28) "BBBBB"
    ["format"]=>
    string(7) "120x600"
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
  }
```

and i have this array:

$izes = array("300x250", "160x600", "728x90", "300x600", "300x300", "120x600", "100x72", "970x250", "750x200", "120x60", "200x600");

I'm trying to do a foreach that if the element of array contains a size doesn't change, and if the hasn't should add the size with count=0

Desire result:

```
 array(2117) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(21) "AAAAAAA"
        ["format"]=>
        string(7) "160x600"
        ["count"]=>
        int(3)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(21) "AAAAAAA"
        ["format"]=>
        string(7) "300x250"
        ["count"]=>
        int(135)
      }
 array(3) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(21) "AAAAAAA"
        ["format"]=>
        string(7) "728x90"
        ["count"]=>
        int(0)
      }
 array(3) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(21) "AAAAAAA"
        ["format"]=>
        string(7) "300x600"
        ["count"]=>
        int(0)
      }
 array(3) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(21) "AAAAAAA"
        ["format"]=>
        string(7) "300x300"
        ["count"]=>
        int(0)
      }
 array(3) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(21) "AAAAAAA"
        ["format"]=>
        string(7) "120x600"
        ["count"]=>
        int(0)
      }
(...) with all sizes
     }
```

I'm trying to do somehting like this:

```
$tmp22222=array();
    foreach ($result as $k=>$v){
        foreach ($std_crt_size as $size) {
            if($v['format']==$size) {
                array_push($tmp22222, $v);
            }
            else{
                $v['format'] = $size;
                $v['count'] = 0;
                array_push($tmp22222, $v);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it always repeat twice

Thanks

Comment: If any code in your original array is already present twice (with different sizes for example), your loop will cause to add all sizes for both instances. You need to restructure your array or change the way you are checking the values.

Comment: hi, and how can i do that?

Comment: it add the value i have before and also same size but with 0

Comment: The original array contains redundant information. The code (e.g. `AAAAAA`) could be a key to an array of different formats/counts. This would (with an adapted check) avoid the duplication.

Comment: Alternatively, you need to track which codes you have already checked in your loop and for recurring codes you just update the count.